# What are the different effects that scale up weapon damage in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, damage-types

In 5e there are all sorts of ways to increase damage from weapons, but nearly all of that additional damage is typed separately from the weapon - eg: extra force damage, fire, etc.

Other than the Enlarge spell and related effects, what other ways are there to specifically increase the damage of the same TYPE as the weapon being used?

Comment: @Nacht [Please do not write answers in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Enlarge spell and related effects".  Any spell?  Spells that specifically say they affect all your damage?

Comment: @Kirt: I assume Isaac's referring to the extra damage from the *enlarge* spell, and other game effects that refer to the *enlarge* spell (or reference that particular spell's effect).

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Thanks for deleting my comments now that they have been added to someone's answers. They have served their purpose.

Answer (score 8):

**[Barbarian Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian)** - While in a rage, Barbarians gain a bonus to strength based weapon damage rolls that increases as they gain levels.  This bonus damage is of the same type as the weapon.

**[College of Swords Bard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#CollegeofSwords)** - **Slashing Flourishes** add a Bardic Inspiration die of damage of the weapon's type to a weapon attack.

**[War Domain Cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#WarDomain)** - **Divine Strike** adds 1d8 damage of the weapon's type to your first hit each turn at level 8 and 2d8 at level 14.

**[Dueling Fighting Style](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#FightingStyle-191)** - This fighting style gives a +2 bonus to damage rolls while wielding a melee weapon in one hand and no other weapons.  This bonus is of the same type as the weapon.

**[Battlemaster Maneuvers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#BattleMaster)** - Several battlemaster maneuvers, including Sweeping Attack, Trip Attack, and others allow you to add a superiority die as damage of the weapon's type to the damage of a weapon attack.

**[Rune Knight Fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#RuneKnight)** - The **Giant's Might** feature allows a Rune Knight to deal an additional 1d6 damage with weapon attacks and unarmed strikes once per turn.  This additional damage is of the same type as the weapon or unarmed strike and increases to 1d8 at level 10 and 1d10 at level 18.

**[Way of the Kensei Monk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayoftheKensei)** - The level 6 **Deft Strike** ability allows you to spend a ki point to add a roll of your Martial Arts die to the damage of an attack with a kensei weapon.  This additional damage is of the same type as the weapon's.

**[Hunter Conclave Ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Hunter)** - The **Colossus Slayer** option for Hunter's Prey at level 3 allows you to add 1d8 damage of the weapon's type to one weapon attack each round that hits a target that is below its hit point maximum.

**[Gloom Stalker Conclave Ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#GloomStalker)** - The **Dread Ambusher** feature allows you to make an additional weapon attack on the first turn of combat when you take the attack action.  If this attack hits, it deals an additional 1d8 damage of the weapon's type.

**[Monster Slayer Conclave Ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#MonsterSlayer)** - The **Slayer's Prey** feature allows you to deal an additional 1d6 damage of the weapon's type once per turn when you hit a designated creature with a weapon attack.

**[Hunter's Mark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark)** - the Ranger spell Hunter's Mark allows you to add 1d6 damage of the weapon's type to any weapon attack that hits the marked target.  Other classes can acquire the spell through the [Fey Touched](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/fey-touched) feat.

**[Variant Ranger Feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/ranger#FavoredFoe)** - The variant level 1 feature, **Favored Foe**, presented in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything allows a Ranger to deal additional damage of the weapon's type once per turn when the Ranger hits a marked target with a weapon attack.  The damage starts at 1d4 and increases at higher levels.

**[Rogue's Sneak Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#SneakAttack-343)** - a Rogue's Sneak Attack adds damage of the same type as the weapon used to deliver the sneak attack.

**[Dragon Slayers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/5385-dragon-slayer), [Giant Slayers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/5388-giant-slayer), and [Corpse Slayers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/1434302-corpse-slayer)** - These magic weapons deal additional damage of their type when hitting Dragons, Giants, and Undead respectively.

Comment: Great survey of many different answers.  Please note that our site does not support links to pirate websites such as wikidot.  It would be great if you replaced your links to those available for free on D&DBeyond.  The roll20 links are probably ok, although not everyone will be able to open them.  Stuff on DDB that is behind paywalls can just be linked to the product.

Comment: Edit: Ninja'd by V2Blast.

Comment: @Kirt: Haha, I was editing as you were posting the comment, I guess :)

Comment: I am quite surprise on the downvote on this answer too.

Answer (score 5):

### [Sneak Attack](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Rogue#toc_5)

> Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.

Answer (score 4):

### Battlemaster Maneuvers

Although only Sweeping Attack specifically calls it out, presumably all of the maneuvers that permit you to add damage to your own or another creature's rolls, are of the same damage type as the initial attack.  This bonus starts at d8 and goes to d12.

Answer (score 2):

#### Spells.

- [*Shillelagh*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shillelagh) improves the damage of a club and of a quarterstaff, increasing it from d6 to d8, and moreover allowing to use one's spellcasting ability instead of Str for damage rolls, since it is usually higher than Str.
- [*Hunter's mark*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark)<sup>*</sup> allows to deal an extra 1d6 damage when making a successful weapon attack.

#### Class Features

- [Way of the Kensei](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayoftheKensei) has a several features that allows one to add damage to weapon attacks (Kensei’s Shot, Deft Strike)
- [Barbarians' Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#Rage-51) adds static bonus to melee attacks, depending on barbarian's level

#### Magic Items

- [*Oil of sharpness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4688-oil-of-sharpness) adds a +3 to damage (and to attack rolls) to a piercing or slashing weapon.
- [*Bracers of archery*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4593-bracers-of-archery) allows to increase the damage of long and short bows weapons by +2
- Any magic item that increase your Str score (*e.g.*, [*gauntlets of ogre power*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4641-gauntlets-of-ogre-power)) for melee weapons or your Dex score (*e.g.*, an [*ioun stone of agility*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4917-ioun-stone-of-agility)) for ranged weapons

---

<sup>*</sup> Courtesy of [Nacht](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/16395/nacht) from the comments.

Comment: In addition to the Kensei's subclass specific features, all Monks can change the damage die of a monk weapon to match their Marital Arts die. At high levels, that will almost always be an increase in damage.

Answer (score 1):

#### *Conjure Barrage* / *Conjure Volley*

> You fire a piece of nonmagical ammunition from a ranged weapon or throw a nonmagical weapon into the air [...] A creature takes [damage] on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one. The damage type is the same as that of the ammunition or weapon.

These spells don't meet the strictest interpretation of the question as they independently deal damage of the same type as a weapon rather than increasing the damage of an attack using the weapon. But it's arguable, and I think it's noteworthy that such a thing even exists.